# Is the sentence "Time to take don't walk" correct? What is it mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, translation

A friend saw the following sentence in a notebook with travel theme, but we couldn't get what it means. It is actually like a journal to write out your trip experiences, but it brings some inspirational sentences.

One of them was:

> Time to take don't walk is left by the memories in the past

[image]

The beginning was the misunderstood part, the auxiliar `don't` with the verb in infinitive form didn't fit after *Time to take*.

What is the explained meaning of this sentence?

And what type of construction is this?

Comment: You have 'walt' in the title, and 'walk' in the question. Also not enough context - which book? Where?

Comment: I've improved it a little

Comment: When I said 'what book?' I meant **please give the title and author of the book, and, hopefully, a link to some text**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the text is not written in meaningful English. It is a question that will help only the asker and no other learner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you are asking about, the answer is 'it is not proper English, written by a native speaker, and may even be a machine translation from Chinese'.

[image]

Comment: You're pretty right Michael! It's actually a made-in-china notebook!

Comment: The English text shown is meaningless.